# Who owns The Lone Ranger these days?

Tags: copyright

News has it that Universal Studios is working on the next Green Hornet reboot, *The Green Hornet and Kato*.  What about Britt Reid's great uncle, the Lone Ranger?  Have the film rights to him reverted away from Disney and Jerry Bruckheimer by now?  If so, is it known where they are at?

Answer (score 2):

## Universal Pictures

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lone_Ranger#Ownership)

> Ownership
>
> From its inception, George W. Trendle had legal ownership of the Lone Ranger and characters associated with the Lone Ranger through his company, The Lone Ranger, Inc. Trendle sold The Lone Ranger, Inc. to oil man and film producer Jack Wrather in 1954 for $3 million. After Wrather died in 1984, his widow, Bonita Granville, sold the Wrather Productions properties to Southbrook International Television Co. in 1985 for $10 million Broadway Video acquired the rights in 1994. Classic Media acquired the rights in 2000. DreamWorks Animation acquired Classic Media in 2012 and renamed the division DreamWorks Classics, which was acquired by NBCUniversal in 2016 for $3.8 billion. **Its Universal Pictures unit currently has the rights to the Lone Ranger.**